# Softlayer Python API failing to order VMs with 1 Gbps network speeds

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am getting this exception when trying to order VMs with the Softlayer Python API.

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks must be ordered with permission Add Compute with Public Network Port.
```

Here is the VSI:

```
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=softlayerusername, api_key=softlayerapikey)
manager = SoftLayer.VSManager(client)
new_vsi = {
        'domain': domain,
        'hostname': hostname + str(n),
        'datacenter': datacenter,
        'dedicated': False,
        'private': False,
        'cpus': number_of_cpus,
        'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_LATEST_64', 
        'hourly': is_hourly_billed,
        'disks': ['100','25'],
        'local_disk': True,
        'memory': 16384,
        'private_vlan': privatevlan,
        'public_vlan': publicvlan,
        'nic_speed':1000
    }
vsi = manager.create_instance(**new_vsi)
```

I can see that the error is related to the nic_speed being set to 1000, but I don't know what it means by the "ordered with permission ..." and how to accomplish that. This is on a private Softlayer account, and there are other machines on the VLAN that have network speeds greater than 1 Gbps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error is because your accounts does not allow new VMs with public network ports, so I recommend you to change the value `'private': False` to `'private': True`, and try again